# Check if a point is inside and object using VTK

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am following [this example](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/PointInsideObject) in order to check if a given point is inside an object.
The following code is the summary of the example using a cube.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource> cubeSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource>::New();
cubeSource->Update();
vtkPolyData* cube = cubeSource->GetOutput();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkSelectEnclosedPoints> selectEnclosedPoints = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSelectEnclosedPoints>::New();
double test[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
points->InsertNextPoint(test);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> pointsPolydata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
pointsPolydata->SetPoints(points);

selectEnclosedPoints->SetInputData(pointsPolydata);
selectEnclosedPoints->SetSurfaceData(cube);
selectEnclosedPoints->Update();

std::cout << "Point: " << selectEnclosedPoints->IsInside(0) << std::endl;
```

When checking a point in a customized polyData object the function does not return what I expected:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> pointsVTK = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
pointsVTK->SetNumberOfPoints(hashMapPoints.size());
////
//insert the points in pointsVTK and vertex, and set labels and sizes
////
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polyData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

polyData->SetPoints(pointsVTK);
polyData->SetVerts(vertsVTK);
point_poly->GetPointData()->AddArray(labels);
point_poly->GetPointData()->AddArray(sizes);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkSelectEnclosedPoints> selectEnclosedPoints = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSelectEnclosedPoints>::New();
double test[3] = {1, 1, 0};

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
points->InsertNextPoint(test);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> pointsPolydata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
pointsPolydata->SetPoints(points);

selectEnclosedPoints->SetInputData(pointsPolydata);
selectEnclosedPoints->SetSurfaceData(polyData);
selectEnclosedPoints->Update();

std::cout << "Point: " << selectEnclosedPoints->IsInside(0) << std::endl;
```

My guess is that the cube structure has other kind of information used by the *selectEnclosedPoints->IsInside* function, but I cannot see what it lacks.

Answer (score 1):

`vtkSelectEnclosedPoints` is the right way to check whether a point is inside an object. However, [the algorithm](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Filters/Modeling/vtkSelectEnclosedPoints.cxx) requires an (ideally closed) surface composed of *cells with a 3D extent*. Your polydata object is composed of *vertices* (which are cells with 0D extent). The difference is explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38515627/3388962).

With the following dummy code (in python), I demonstrate how a polydata object can be constructed that can be used with `vtkSelectEnclosedPoints`:

```
# Create poly data object
surfacePoly = vtk.vtkPolyData()
surfacePoly.SetPoints(points)
surfacePoly.SetPolys(cells)   # 2D cells, not verts!

# ...

# Use surfacePoly as input
selectEnclosed = vtk.vtkSelectEnclosedPoints()
selectEnclosed.SetInputData(pointsPoly)
selectEnclosed.SetSurfaceData(surfacePoly)
selectEnclosed.Update()
```

See the [vtk example collection](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/) (section "Cells") for more examples how to create poly data objects. In case you operate with a point cloud, you first need to compute a convex hull or define a surface around your points. [See here](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Boneyard/Cxx/PolyData/ConvexHullDelaunay3D) for an example.

---

**Update:** Added example how to extract the convex hull with [`vtkDelaunay3D`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDelaunay3D.html). Make sure to read also the notes in the documentation. The computation of a Delaunay triangulation tends to be more stable if the points are not forming regular patterns.

```
polyPoints = vtk.vtkPolyData()
polyPoints.SetPoints(points)
triangulation = vtk.vtkDelaunay3D()
triangulation.SetInputData(polyPoints)
# Tuning parameter.
# triangulation.SetOffset(100.0)
triangulation.Update()
# Extract the surface
convexHull = vtk.vtkDataSetSurfaceFilter()
convexHull.SetInputConnection(triangulation.GetOutputPort())
convexHull.Update()
# And retrieve the corresponding polydata object.
surfacePoly = convexHull.GetOutput()
```

Comment: Since I do not have information about cells in my polydata, I'll try to construct a polygon with the points and then check if the point is inside with something like this: https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/PointInPolygon

Comment: In case you have just points, you need to specify what "inside" means. I suggested to compute the convex hull around the points, have you tried this? I added a link to an example.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the function "isInside" couldn't find the point inside the object. I strongly believe that it is cause by the lack of information about cells.

Comment: True, there is possibly one thing missing in the example I was referring to. You need to apply the [`vtkDataSetSurfaceFilter`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSetSurfaceFilter.html) after `vtkDelaunay3D` to extract the surface. Furthermore, you might have to play around with the `SetOffset()` option of `vtkDelaunay3D` in case the result does not look as intended.

Comment: Added some code that illustrates how to extract a convex hull (this worked at least for me)

Comment: Note that if you're in python you can take advantage of scipy's excellent ConvexHull class for a 500X speedup! https://gist.github.com/flutefreak7/bd621a9a836c8224e92305980ed829b9